# Add python modules to Azure

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, azure, azure-webjobs

When I run a python script that I set up on WebJobs in Azure - I get the following error:

```
      import MySQLdb
 ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
 job failed due to exit code 1
```

I found some articles that seem to suggest to install python modules to a directory created on the webapp.  How/Where would I install those modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

http://nicholasjackson.github.io/azure/python/python-packages-and-azure-webjobs/
(from the site):

> Step 1.
>
> If you are using OSX and the default Python 2.7 install your packages
>   installed with pip will be in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages,
>   create a folder called site-packages in the root of your python job
>   and copy any packages you need for your job into it.
>
> Step 2
>
> Next you need to modify your run.py or any other file which requires
>   access to the package files. At the top of the file add….
>
> ```
> import sys  
> sys.path.append("site-packages")
> ```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you - I had not come across that site.